# How Can I change the route config to the custom route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I tried to change and optimize my website URL to the SEO friendly Url. I mean I change the url Like ~/Home/Contact to ~/contact and etc. I change the ~/Home/Index URL to ~/home as well.

When I run my website because I add the attr [Route("~/home")] to my index action application can't find my default route.

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

I don't know how can I change my MapRoute to my new SEO Friendly URL.
I don't want to loss my mvc URL Pattern as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this class in App_Start folder:

```
public static class RoutingConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

            #region IgnoreRoutes
            routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ico");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.png");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.jpg");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.gif");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.txt");
            #endregion

            routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
           // AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults:
                    new
                    {
                        controller = MVC.Home.Name,
                        action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Index,
                        id = UrlParameter.Optional
                    },
                namespaces: new[] {$"{typeof (RoutingConfig).Namespace}.Controllers"}
                );
        }
```

and use this in `Global.asax.cs` `Application_Start` method.

```
  RoutingConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

I used from `T4MVC nuget package`.